# Download file from URL through macro and save it on a location

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to download a file from a website and want to save at a desired location, while doing this my code get stuck on the save as dialog box. After this I am not able to pass the location path after that dialog box get open.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [edit] your original question and add the code you already have. Show up on which line you got errors (and which) or where you got stuck.

Comment: Easy option is to usually try a cheeky `.sendkeys`, emulating the keyboard presses required to proceed

Comment: @attri, i had exactly the same problem but i solved it by adding "c:\" to the third line.

Comment: SendKeys "%s" after this line a save as dialog box appear now I have to save my file at a location with the help of variable in which path value is present

Answer (score 6):

If you are trying to download a file from a url then you can use the method in this blog.

[Download a file from url using VBA](http://www.excelvbasolutions.com/2014/09/download-file-from-url-using-vba.html)

But you will need to change saving path, file type etc. accordingly. It will be helpful if you can post your current code.

Comment: You can try it like this.